# Scheme-Source expression failed to match any pattern

Tags: scheme

I am writing a program in Scheme to manipulate some lists and some self defined types. I have written the following short code and it gives me the following error:

`Source expression failed to match any pattern`

Why does this error crop up? I think this is because I used let* but I double checked the syntax and my usage is correct. Here is my code:

```
(define (create-evaluation-link wp)
  (define x (get-first-word wp))
  (define y (get-second-word wp))
  (if (null? (ListLink x y))
      ((EvaluationLink 
        (MSTLinkNode "MA")
        (ListLink x y)))
      (let* ((ll (ListLink x y))
             (in (cog-incoming-set ll))
             (mst (get-mst-node in))))))
```

Am I doing something wrong?

get-mst-node is a function in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `let*` form is missing the body (the code that uses the bindings). Even if the body simply returns `mst`, like so:

```
(let* ((ll (ListLink x y))
       (in (cog-incoming-set ll))
       (mst (get-mst-node in)))
  mst)
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that the body was compulsory.